# Does Buford wear a Punisher shirt?

Tags: reference, costume, phineas-and-ferb, toy-story

I noticed that Buford Van Stomm from *Phineas and Ferb* wears a black tee shirt with short sleeves, and an approximation of a skull on the front

[image: https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/phineasandferb/images/1/1c/Buford_Van_Stomm.PNG]

Is there any correlation with the skull image that Frank Castle wears on his shirt, in the role of The Punisher?

[image: http://cdn2us.denofgeek.com/sites/denofgeekus/files/styles/main_wide/public/2016/03/punisher-1-maleev-variant-1.jpg]

---

Also noted that Crash from The Bettys wears a tee shirt with a similar motif, but different colours.

[image: https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/phineasandferb/images/8/86/Crash.jpg]

Also Sid Philips from [*Toy Story*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toy_Story) (1995) wears a similar shirt.

[image: https://pbs.twimg.com/media/Cq35w0_WIAQ4mec.jpg]

Is there any connection between these?

Comment: Doubtful. The skull is a universal symbol of "bad guy". In phineas and ferb, buford is a "bad kid" or, the tough kid even though he is friendly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned by DustinDavis in comments, it is a universal symbol for "bad guy". Or in the words of TV Tropes [Skeleton Motif](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SkeletonMotif):

> This trope can take many forms. While some characters may use real bones, photographs, or detailed drawings of bones to construct their motif, something as subtle as a pattern on a T-shirt or a piece of jewelry that vaguely resembles a skull can be just as effective.

Also the same TV Tropes link talks about Toy story too:

> In Toy Story, Sid (something closest to a "villain" in the movie) wears a skull T-shirt.

And lists many such similar examples too like *Bully Jimbo* from *The Simpsons* and it's not even limited to Disney property only.

Crash from *Phineas and Ferb* can be debated for not being evil but she did do mean stuff to Candace and Stacy. And Stacy earned the similar shirt as an act of being a fangirl.

Comment: Also this: [Are we the baddies?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8JOpPNra4bw). "*Why skulls, though?*"